# I didn't get the Critic badge. Why?

Tags: support

My issue seems to be the opposite of this question:
[I seem to have been awarded the Critic badge incorrectly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308641/i-seem-to-have-been-awarded-the-critic-badge-incorrectly)

I placed a downvote on an answer on SO, but I didn't get awarded the Critic badge. I refreshed, same thing.

Here's an image: [image: downvote but no critic]

Does anyone know what the issue could be? I have the Supporter badge for first upvote.

Comment: How long did you wait? Badges can take a few minutes to get sometimes.

Comment: Badges are awarded in batches - a job runs and awards them. They are not awarded in real-time.

Comment: @Oded Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck It was 07:56 GMT at the time of the downvote, and it's 09:51 GMT now.

Comment: Looks like people are trying to get the critic badge using your question :(

Comment: @AlexanderDerck LOL, thankfully meta doesn't impact reputation(I hope, I don't want to find out I'm back to 1 tomorrow; earning rep on SO is hard.)

Comment: @cst1992 No meta doesn't affect reputation on stack overflow

Comment: Patience is the virtue..

Comment: @PrashantShahi This post is old. Wayyyy too old.

Comment: @cst1992 Still people are landing up on this question like you and me for example... So, this can pass on like some old man's wisdom.

Comment: @cst1992 did you ever get your badge?

Comment: @BenJones yup, I did :P

Comment: I also did not get the critic badge after my first down vote.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Badges are awarded in batches - a job runs and awards them.

They are not awarded in real-time.

Different badges are on different schedules (depends on how intensive the query for them is), some are on a 5 minute schedule, some on an hourly and some on a daily schedule.

Comment: Sir i have done the same thing but i did not get this badge . My question is when will i get this badge and downvoting the answer they deduct my 1 upvote also.

Comment: I've been up and downvoting questions for a little over a year (stack overflow) and don't have the badge, it's not this in my case

Comment: You seem to have gotten it 14 minutes ago. Nothing to do with me... as I have not been an employee for quite some time.

Comment: Yeah strange, I had quite a few come though. I think it may be because I messed around with some of my contact details and such on my account, and it connected to another stack overflow account I had on my gmail that I made by mistake. May have jogged the system or something. Either that or I had it and changing account stuff removed it and then it re-added somehow?

Comment: @Sunil downvoting the question is free but to downvote an answer cost us a reputation, that's the rule.

Comment: @ZobiaKanwal can there be a way to show this when an answer is downvoted? Most people might miss this and lose reputation before figuring out the reason